# BDD Mockito - alias for verify(...) when using argument captor?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mockito, tdd, bdd

I wrote the test which uses `BBDMockito` and `Argument Captor`. Argument Captor is used only to capture callback and invoke `onDataNotAvailable()`, **not for the verification**.

```
@Test
public void loadNoItemFromRepository_showsMissingItem() {
    //given
    itemDetailPresenter = new ItemDetailPresenter(UNCHECKED_ITEM.getId(), itemsRepository, itemDetailView);
    given(itemDetailView.isActive()).willReturn(true);

    //when
    itemDetailPresenter.load();
    verify(itemsRepository).getItem(eq(UNCHECKED_ITEM.getId()), getItemCallbackArgumentCaptor.capture());
    getItemCallbackArgumentCaptor.getValue().onDataNotAvailable();

    //then
    then(itemDetailView).should().showMissingItem();
}
```

`Verify` placed in `//when` section is confusing because the name suggests it should be placed in the verification section (`//then`). Is there an alias for `verify()` so I can use it with argument captor and the name will be more appropriate for `//when`?

**Edited:**

The code which I want to test is if `itemDetailView.showMissingItem()` was called.

```
public void load() {
    (...)
    itemsRepository.getItem(itemId, new ItemsDataSource.GetItemCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLoaded(Item item) {
            (...)
            if (nonNull(item))
                showItem(item);
            else
                itemDetailView.showMissingItem();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataNotAvailable() {
            (...)
            itemDetailView.showMissingItem();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why is it placed in the //when section to begin with?  It belongs in the //then section.  The verify statement will fail the test if the expected method isn't invoked.  Then if you want to do additional validation of the arguments used in the invocation the argument captor is used.  Both are validating things.

Comment: I'm checking if `showMissingItem()` is called, I'm not checking if `getItem` is called. The argument captor is used only to call `onDataNotAvailable()`. How should my test look like?

Answer (score 1):

`verify(...)` is an assertion, it's used to check a method was/wasn't called and how many times - it belongs in the `//then` section

I see you're also using an argumentCaptor but aren't checking anything with it, the proper process there would be to assert that the captured value (`getItemCallbackArgumentCapture.getValue()` contains/equals a value you expect).

Comment: But I have to invoke `onDataNotAvailable()`? Is there a better solution than using an argument captor?

Comment: Well invoking it from the argument captor won't actually help as it won't impact the output of your test - you shouldn't be trying to call any method code other than what you're trying to test. What are you trying to achieve by calling onDataNotAvailable()?

Comment: I have to invoke `onDataNotAvailable()` because I'm testing what is called in this method. Check my edit please. If you know better solution then calling `onDataNotAvailable()` from the ArgumentCaptor, let me know.

Comment: I see, if you call `load()` in your test that should call `onDataNotAvailable()` anyway right? Basically, you want to set up your `itemDetailPresenter` so that when `load()` is called it in-turn calls `onDataNotAvailable()` without you **manually** calling it (as then you're not really testing the behaviour and your `then(itemDetailView).should().showMissingItem();` will always fail). The idea here is to setup (during the _when_ section) the test case in such a way that when you call the method under test it behaves as your expect in your _then_ section